# Characterization of the elements of a quotient ring

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, algebraic-curves

I'm in trouble with the following exercise:

Consider the ideal $ I = (X^2-Y^3,Y^2-Z^3) $ in the polynomial ring $ k[X,Y,Z] $, where $k$ is any algebraically closed field. Show that every element of $ k[X,Y,Z]/I $ is the residue of an element $ A + XB + YC + XYD $, for some $A,B,C,D\in k[Z]$.

I hope you can help me with the solution or some hint to prove this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\overline{P}$ be an element of this quotient ring (call it $A$). In $A$, call $x$,$y$ and $z$ the images of $X$, $Y$ and $Z$.

Then in $A$, $x^2 = y^3$, so you can replace all even powers of $x$ a power of $y$. This means that you can assume that $P$ is a polynomial in $x$, $y$ and $z$ such that the only power of $x$ that appears is $1$.

Then since $y^2 = z^3$ you can aslo replace all even powers of $y$ by powers of $z$, so you can aslo assume that the only power of $y$ that appears in $P$ is $1$.

This gives you the expected form.

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't understand why I don't realize the facts you are using. Again, thank you!

Comment: Glad you liked the answer. If it adressed your problem, you should accept it so the question is marked as answered.