# Which is true for the ring $\dfrac{\mathbb{R}[x,y]}{\langle x^3-y^2\rangle}$

Tags: commutative-algebra, principal-ideal-domains, integral-domain, unique-factorization-domains, polynomial-rings

The ring $$\dfrac{\mathbb{R}[x,y]}{\langle x^3-y^2\rangle}$$

a) is unique factorization domain and principal ideal domain

b) is unique factorization domain.

c) unique factorization domain but not principal ideal domain

d) not integral domain

$\textbf{My Try}$

I take homomorphism. $$\phi:\mathbb{R}[x,y]\to \mathbb{R}[x]$$ such that $$\phi(f(x,y))=f(x^2,x^3)$$

Here, $\dfrac{\mathbb{R}[x,y]}{\langle x^3-y^2\rangle}$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}[x]$ with kernel $\langle x^3-y^2\rangle$ because $\phi$ doesn't has image  $x \in \mathbb{R}[x]$.

But it is isomorphic to $A=\{\sum a_i x^i \in \mathbb{R}[x]~|~a_1=0\}$, which is not P.I.D because $A$ generated by $\langle x^2,1\rangle$. So option **(b)** and **(c)** are true.

**But in answer key option a and b are true.**

They showed it is isomorphic to $R[x]$ and $\phi$ is surjective. But clearly it is not surjective.  Please help me, i am stuck.

Comment: It's also not a UFD - $y^2 = x^3$, but both $x$ and $y$ are irreducible (for example by looking at the degrees of the images under $\phi$).  But it is an integral domain since you showed it embeds into the integral domain $\mathbb{R}[x]$.

Comment: Use `\langle` and `\rangle`, not `<` and `>`. The latter are operators, so they have extra space assuming there will be formulas on both sides of them; the former are delimeters, so there is only space on the "inside" of them.

Comment: Also, use `**bold text**` for boldface; don't stick it inside Mathjax to use `\textbf`.

Comment: Thanks for editing

Comment: Please write the answer. It would be helpful for me.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon It definitely needs $\phi(x)=x^2$, $\phi(y)=x^3$. For otherwise $x^3-y^2$ won't be in the kernel. Often this ring is handled by introducing the formal fraction $t=y/x$ when $x=t^2$, $y=t^3$, and the homomorphism maps this ring to a proper subring of $\Bbb{R}[t]$.

Comment: Mind you, I think all of $a,b,c,d$ are false.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Oh yes, indeed we have $$(y-x)(y+x)= y^2 - x^2 = (x^3 - x^2) = x^2(x-1)$$ which shows that it can't be a UFD for sure, so $a,b$ are certainly false. The last one I'd expect to be false as well. As I was writing an answer and experimenting I realized it was going wrong, but thanks for intervening.

Comment: @user895538 Your thoughts on the factorization above showing it's not a UFD? Does the answer key provide an explanation?

Comment: And, as you pointed out, $\phi$ is not an isomorphism. The image is the span of $1,x^2,x^3,x^4,\ldots$ with $x$ missing. This is a well studied class of rings in algebraic geometry. The details can get [a bit more complicated](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3575807/11619). I'm not an expert, so what's *complicated* to me is still piece of cake to the connoisseurs.